# Given that Zygote does not support mutation, how does Recur gets away with it?

Tags: julia

From Flux.jl's source code [here](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/1605a010398ea2dae423ca8e346d19e213594de5/src/layers/recurrent.jl#L37):

```
mutable struct Recur{T}
  cell::T
  init
  state
end

Recur(m, h = hidden(m)) = Recur(m, h, h)

function (m::Recur)(xs...)
  h, y = m.cell(m.state, xs...)
  m.state = h
  return y
end
```

it looks like `Recur` struct, which is used for every recurrent layer, does mutation of its `state` field in the forward pass. But Zygote.jl does not support mutation, so why is this not throwing something like `ERROR: Mutation is not supported!` as it usually does in such cases?

**For a context of where this came up**: I was implementing my custom stateful layer. Initially, I just defined `MyCustomRecurrentCell` [similarly](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/1605a010398ea2dae423ca8e346d19e213594de5/src/layers/recurrent.jl#L61) to `RNNCell` and relied on `Recur` to handle the `MyCustomRecurrentCell`'s state mutation, just like `RNNCell` does. But then I discovered that because `Recur`'s fields are not type annotated I was getting `Any` type outputs for my state which was propagating to all the other layer and I was getting `Any` everywhere because of this. Then I filed [this issue](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/issues/1092) and decided to reimplement `Recur` with type annotated fields. When I did so, I'm now getting something like `ArgumentError: type does not have a definite number of fields` error. So I was wondering how is `Recur` able to get away with mutating state?